# Proving subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Question:** Prove that the following sets are subgroups of $G$, where $G$ is the group of functions that go from the unitary circumference in the plane in the unitary circumference.

(a)The set of functions that leave fixed a finite number of points of $A$, where $A=$set of points on the circumference.

Attempt: Let $S=\{h: h(x)=x~~ \text{for finitely many $x$}\}$. Let $f,g\in S$. .

Then $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=f(x)=x$. So $f,g\in S$.

Let $i(x)=x $for all $x$, since $i$ fixes also finite number of points so $i\in S$. Then $(f\circ i)(x)=f(i(x))=f(x)$. Similarly $(i\circ f)(x)=f(x)$.

I am facing problem with to get inverse of function.

Kindly give me a hint to proceed.

Comment: What is the "unitary circumference"?

Comment: If point $(x,y)$ lies in unitary circumference, then $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: You mean unit circle, not unitary circumference.

Comment: I mean unit circle's circumference.

Comment: No, in english, that is indeed called the unit circle. Also, under what operation do the functions form a group? I would imagine you need some constraints on said functions.

Comment: Alright! Under composition operation.

Comment: Okay. That is not a group. Fx. the function mapping $G$ to one point is not invertible. Is it mentioned what functions on $G$ we are talking about? We can at most talk about bijective functions being a group here.

Comment: Here given in problem $G$ is a group. So existence of inverse of $f$ is sure.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267361/prove-the-subgroup).

Comment: Both questions are different. Kindely see carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, given our discussion in the comments, I can give you an answer.

We have to first assume that $G$ is a group under composition, since the set of all functions from $G$ to $G$ does not satisfy that. With that given, we can give a negative proof of the statement:

**Statement**: The set of functions that leave fixed a finite number of points of $S^1$ is *not* a subgroup of $G$

**Proof:** Let $H$ be the above mentioned set. For $H$ to be a subgroup, it needs to contain the identity of the group $G$. But the identity of $G$ fixes *all* elements of $S^1$, which is an infinite set, so $H$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Identity function fixes also finite number of points.

Comment: Aha, so I guess the set is the set of functions with at least 1 fixed point?

Comment: yup. I think so.

Comment: Any idea about inverse. This problem is given by the professor. So I don't think the problem is wrong.

Comment: But that set is also not a subgroup. I'm pretty sure you must have written something wrong from the problem. We're not using the fact that $S^1$ is a metric space, so we are only using that $S^1$ is an infinite set, which seems strange.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I think you are missing some information in this problem. Try typing everything out that your professor said.

Comment: The problem is provided in documemt mode. I typed everything what is said by the professor.

Comment: I suspect that the finite number of points refers to a *fixed (finite) set* $A$ of points. So elements of the group fix the elements of $A$ and can do whatever they want with the other points on the circle

Comment: This is a companion question to an earlier question where the group elements fixed everything *outside* a finite set $A$

Comment: @Vincet: Question gets fit if $A$ is finite right?